# I was expecting that the result would be all elements of the array,but it didnt go well.Can anyone help me?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

why my code is not printing all values of the array?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int *a;
   a=&arr[0];
   int i=0;
   for(i=arr[i];i<5;i++){
   printf("%d",*a);
       a=a+1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try this with `int arr[5] = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5};` and see what happens.

Comment: `for(i=arr[i];i<5;i++)` -> `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Comment: wow!thanks sir I got that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is homework, correct? Check the index of your loop. What you want to do is that your `for` loops five times, regardless of the content of your array.

Comment: yeah I found my mistake sir,its day 2 of learning array and I understood what you said very clearly:D

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int arr[5]={5,5,5,5,5};
   int *a;
   a=&arr[0];
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   printf("%d",*a);
       a=a+1;
   }
} this worked sir and I got you

Comment: @pratikneupane don't put code other than oneliners in a comment, as you can see it's pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the first index of the array as i instead you should take i as 0 so that it will iterate from **0 to 4** taking all index. Instead you are starting from **1 to 4**. Here is the code if needed:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int *a;
   a=&arr[0];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);i++){//You can replace "sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])" with 5
   printf("%d",*a);
       a=a+1;
   }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is most likely confusing for a beginner.

Comment: You can instead use the length of the array. Which is 5 in this case. I have added it in the doc comment